# How do I make sure the SWF file from my AIR project can't be opened like a regular SWF file?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, security, air

I'm making a game with Flash CS5.5 and exporting it to a APK file (AIR for Android).

The trouble is that the APK file is really just a ZIP file, so you can extract the content and inside there is my game as a regular SWF file. Anyone can upload this to any website and play the game there.

I don't want the SWF file to work unless opened like it should, inside the APK file through Android.

Is there any way to know through ActionScript 3 code if the SWF file has been extracted from the APK file and has been opened as a normal SWF file?

Answer (score 1):

A swf will "open" no matter what.  You might however, do a check in your Document Class for what the OS is before deciding whether or not to actually allow the swf to run any more code.  Look at flash.system.Capabilities and you'll find tools that let you sniff the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The Capabilities.os isn't highly reliable, as a linux user could view it in a web browser / desktop (My HTC androic reports Linux OS).

As far as I've seen, version is specific to the player version and should always report "AND [version string]" - example "AND 10,2,150,60"

```
if( flash.system.Capabilities.version.slice(0,3).toUpperCase() != 'AND' ){
    // ....oh noes! hide and destroy everything!
}
```

P.s. I +1'd you scriptocalypse for flash.system.Capabilities  :)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version

It's been around for a while (see player 9 / air 1.0 / etc) and is defined in the API ref, so its not just a hack

version property
version:String  [read-only]
Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 9, AIR 1.0, Flash Lite 4
Specifies the Flash Player or Adobe® AIR® platform and version information. The format of the version number is: platform majorVersion,minorVersion,buildNumber,internalBuildNumber. Possible values for platform are "WIN", ` "MAC", "LNX", and "AND". Here are some examples of version information:

```
 WIN 9,0,0,0  // Flash Player 9 for Windows
 MAC 7,0,25,0   // Flash Player 7 for Macintosh
 LNX 9,0,115,0  // Flash Player 9 for Linux
 AND 10,2,150,0 // Flash Player 10 for Android
```

Comment: Alright, this works. Although it's a little scary that I have to rely on a string that may not be the same on all future OR current Android platforms. And non-Android platforms could also being the version with "AND"...

Comment: Is there some way of finding out whether or not the application is being launched through AIR? Like for example on Windows you could check if right-clicking was supported, if it is the SWF file is played in AIR otherwise it is played by the Flash player. However right-clicking is not available on phones. Got any ideas? It would be cool if I could move the AIR file between systems (iPhone/Android/Win/Linux/Mac) without having to code too much. Just as long as it's only playable through AIR and not directly as a SWF file it is fine.

Comment: Thats a different question! :P  Just off the top of my head, some ideas : 
implement AIR-specific functionality (pull something from that air.* package and you can try/catch it)
sniff the NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion or
something similar, if it isn't running in air, you'll know  :)

Comment: Also, I wouldn't worry about the strign method - its actually part of the the api reference, i.e. it won't be changed lightly and without deprecation support through at least a few versions etc.  [See here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version)

Comment: You have calmed my worries, if it's part of the referances it should be OK. It's odd that they have no value for iPhone though, what appears then? "MAC"? That would probably also appear if you ran the SWF file on a Macintosh... So the method is good right now when I only export for Android but it's not enough if I intend to release for more platforms. That's why I don't think think it's a "different question" like you wrote (see the original true question in the browser title bar). I would rather have a complete solution here instead of making a new reformed question on stackoverflow. =)

Answer (score 0):

First Thing to note: technically there are absolutely no ways you can stop a patient and dedicated person from unpacking and *trying* to use you SWF on the web.

BUT what you really can do is you can make a hacker suffer and have hard times reversing your code. In reality that's the only thing that matters: you may state that your app is protected when the cost of efforts and profit of breaking the defences is comparable to the cost of defending the app.

- In your code check anything you can to detect a launch in Android environment. OS, like scriptocalypse suggested and/or availability of Android API. Block application from starting in inappropriate envirenment. Or, if you like, change the app flow so that it starts, but works with major disabilities, if not launched on Android.
- use obfuscator like [secureSWF](http://www.kindi.com/features-editions.php) or [SWFEncrypt](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/)

Personally, I use secureSWF but there are plenty of them -- choose to your liking.

Comment: Do you have any tip about an obfuscator program that doesn't require me to spend more money than I expect to earn on my project? :P Like a free one?

Comment: Recently I've come across this thing: [Special Offer for FGL Community](http://www.kindi.com/fgl-offer.php). Check it out. If I understand it correctly, you can get a free personal license if you are a member of FGL community. I did not try it myself, so I can not share the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't noticed that you could get a free license, that's amazing! I didn't have to sign up for any community either, just give them my mail and click a confirm link in the mail. That's pretty generous of them, though I kind of get a feeling that there must be some catch that I won't discover until later. Hope not!

Comment: Please drop a line if you discover something. :)

Comment: And btw you could accept an answer here just out of simple politeness. :)